# Difference between http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ vs http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Tags: maven

What is the difference between http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ and http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/?

Are http://search.maven.org/, http://mvnrepository.com/ indexing the same artifacts?

Comment: Yes they are. This is all Maven Central.

Answer (score 19):

In the version 3.0.3 the default url was http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.

It got changed to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ with version 3.0.4

Refer to following link for more details "[use CNAME or repo to provide more stability](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5151)"

Comment: Still they refer same repository? or they are mirrors of each other?. When we use 3.0.5 version if we specify `<ropository> <id>central</id><name>Maven </name> <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 </url></repository>` what will happen?

Comment: As of January 15th 2020, http is not supported anymore so update your links to `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` and/or `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/`. There is still a http endpoint at `http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/`.
https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334