# How do I know which maven dependency should be add to pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, dependency-management

How can I find correct maven dependency when I have to use a class that I have never used

***Unresolved className***:-

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a search via this interface https://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav. Many IDEs also expose a GUI front-end to this search capability and will be able to find the artifact for you.

Comment: I think it works, but I still  have a problem: My project require spring-web dependency and spring-webmvc dependency, however spring-webmvc also depends on spring-web, so should I just import spring-webmvc?

Comment: maven handles transitive dependencies, so yes, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=search+org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter+maven) which will quickly points out to [org.springframework/spring-web/3.0.2.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/3.0.2.RELEASE).

You can then go back to [org.springframework/spring-web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web) to look for the right version.

Comment: I believe the other answer should be preferable and better in terms of Maven artifact lookup. Google might link to the same as well but wouldn't always suggest or list out the version and their release dates.

Comment: @nullpointer I tried it and it did not return any result: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.spring.framework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter%22

Comment: Indeed, it fails to find. But in that case, how about managing the repositories to look into for such searches?

Comment: @nullpointer I don't know, by the time you manage said repo, my google search would already have solved the problem, and I would have completed the pom.xml with the right dependency.

Comment: My question was even if the google search leads me an artifact version, how do I download it if the repositories for it are not included in my project? Including the dependency would result into a failure during build without it.

Comment: @nullpointer Including the dependency would download the jar into your local maven repo.

Comment: From where would it download the jar? (which repository, that's what I am asking, *how about managing the repositories* ?)...For one thing, since you can't search it on maven central, not from there at least, which serves as the default repository.

Comment: @nullpointer the maven repo central, for instance: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/5.0.0.RELEASE. Add that to your pom.xml and you are good to go.

Comment: Not unless OP specifies explicitly to download from there.

Comment: @nullpointer that is a job for a ~/.m2/settings.xml: those are the settings specifying where you are downloading from. I assume here this is already the case.

Comment: Be it settings.xml or pom.xml of the module itself...*that is a job for a ~/.m2/settings.xml: those are the settings specifying* would not be done automatically and the OP must specify any other repository than maven central to download from.(if be the case)

Comment: @nullpointer in this case, not need to specify another repo: maven central is enough. Just adding the right dependency will allow the OP to move on.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web is not the central. The one looked by default is http://repo1.maven.org/. This is where the https://search.maven.org looks for artifacts while searching as well.

Comment: @nullpointer this is all central (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155159/difference-between-http-repo-apache-maven-org-maven2-vs-http-repo1-maven-or#comment59947395_36155159)

Comment: Ideally I don't see all of them being used as the default maven central for a project setup and built fresh, unless I explicitly mention them. But I rest my case with the hope that OP can come up and state as to what worked for them.

Comment: @nullpointer My point is: The OP has most probably *already* a settings.xml mirroring central. He/she is already downloading dependencies, except for this one class. Google, edit your pom.xml, add the dependency, `mvn install`, done.