# How to get a pom on maven via https by <parent> tags?

Tags: maven, ignite

I try to install Apache Ignite 2.9.1(the latest version) on my pc by the source code.

in which I need to run

`mvn clean install -Pall-java,all-scala,licenses -DskipTests`

However, there is a error that I can't get the pom file from maven repository.

```
Downloading from repo1: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM org.apache.ignite:ignite-parent:1 (E:\Ignite\apache-ignite-2.9.1-src\apache-ignite-2.9.1-src\parent\pom.xml) points at org.apache.ignite:apache-ignite instead of org.apache:apache, please verify your project structure @ org.apache.ignite:ignite-parent:1, E:\Ignite\apache-ignite-2.9.1-src\apache-ignite-2.9.1-src\parent\pom.xml, line 29, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.ignite:ignite-parent:1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:16 from/to repo1 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Transfer failed for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16.pom 501 HTTPS Required and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.apache.ignite:ignite-parent:1, E:\Ignite\apache-ignite-2.9.1-src\apache-ignite-2.9.1-src\parent\pom.xml, line 29, column 13
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.ignite:apache-ignite:2.9.1 (E:\Ignite\apache-ignite-2.9.1-src\apache-ignite-2.9.1-src\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.ignite:ignite-parent:1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:16 from/to repo1 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Transfer failed for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16.pom 501 HTTPS Required and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.apache.ignite:ignite-parent:1, E:\Ignite\apache-ignite-2.9.1-src\apache-ignite-2.9.1-src\parent\pom.xml, line 29, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

It is because the maven has transferred all the http to https, so I should use
`https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16.pom`
instead of
`http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16.pom`

But when I find the pom.xml in the Ignite folder, I find it is was:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
        <version>16</version>
</parent>
```

The pom file I can't get is declared by a <parent> tag.

So, how could I transfer the url to download this pom?
Further, There is often a a lot of http url(dependences, pom, ...) in some old maven project, is there any tool that can transfer these http url to https automatically?

In addtion, my maven version is 3.6.3 and my {MAVEN_HOME}/conf/setting.xml is

```
<mirrors>
     <mirror>
        <id>alimaven</id>
        <name>aliyun maven</name>
        <url>https://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>

<profile>
    <id>maven-https</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories> 
</profile>
```

Comment: Doesn't go to `http://` for me, please double check your Maven settings.

Comment: Ah, I have put the setting file in the question......Do you think there is something wrong? I am really confused...... Could you build Apache Ignite successfully?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this question has been partially [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764749/requests-to-http-repo1-maven-org-maven2-return-a-501-https-required-status-an) already.
Most likely you have an outdated Maven version (< 3.2.3). That's the reason why your build is trying to reach `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`. Have a look at the [article](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334) describing this behavior. Your workaround with settings doesn't work probably because `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` used to be the default one before Maven 3.0.4, but you specified `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` in your `settings.xml`.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156652/5558122) is the answer confirming that. As far as I understand you have 3 basic options:

- update Maven to some newer version (3.2.3+)
- change `pom.xml` to reflect the correct endpoint

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

- modify `settings.xml` to contain a proper mirror

```xml
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>centralhttps</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        <name>Maven central https</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to note that my maven version is 3.6.3, so maybe these is something wrong besides that? I have editted the question.